# createMock and non-abstract methods in an abstract class

Tags: java, easymock

I have an `abstract` class that I'd like to mock out for testing purposes:

```
public abstract class Foo {
    public abstract void bar();
    public void baz() {
      System.out.print("Hi from baz!");
    }
}
```

If I use easyMock `Foo mock = createNiceMock(Foo.class)` and then call `mock.baz()` I get a `java.lang.NullPointerException`.  If I change `baz()` to `final`, things work swimmingly (I assume this has to do with the fact EasyMock can't mock `final` methods) but I would like to be able to call `baz()` without doing this.

Is there a way to create a mock object using EasyMock that allows me to call my non-`abstract` methods?

The one workaround I'm currently using is:

```
Foo mock = new Foo() {
    @Override
    public void bar() {
        return;
    }
}
```

but this is super ugly.

Answer (score 0):

So I found a solution to my question.  You can create partial mocks in EasyMock:

```
Foo mock = EasyMock.createMockBuilder(Foo.class) 
                .addMockedMethod("bar")
                .createNiceMock();
```

The one caveat to this is that if the class has instance variables, as you are not using `new` they won't be initialized!  If anyone has a workaround for this aspect, that would be useful.  That is creating a partial for this class:

```
public abstract class Foo {
    public double myInstanceVariable = 2;
    public abstract void bar();
    public void baz() {
      System.out.print("Hi from baz!");
    }
}
```

Where it's possible to call `mock.myInstanceVariable` and get `2`.

Comment: Regarding your workaround, you can just set the field...

        Field field =  Foo.class.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
  field.setAccessible(true);
  field.set(setFieldOn, value);